# How to move player on unity3D?

Tags: unity, c#

I checked the input settings. I added a speed value. I also added Time.deltaTime, but the body is not moving.

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed; 
    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start () { 
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
    } 

    void FixedUpdate () { 
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); 
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical); 
        rb.AddForce(movement * speed); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: How is it configured in the inspector? Your "speed" variable is actually a force, so it is possible that it is so low that friction prevents it from moving.

Comment: Please, follow the very first project people follow when learning Unity. It's called [Roll a Ball](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial)

Comment: I'm following that project

Comment: You must initialize your speed value with anything except zero.
Try to change it's value at run time to see what happens.

Answer (score -2):

You should multiple speed and deltatime

```
rb.AddForce = (time.DeltaTime * speed * movement)
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question. If the object is not moving at all, reducing the force by multiplying it by a Time.deltaTime value that's less than one will tend to make it even more reluctant to move, not less. ;) Also, OP mentions that they've tried this already: "I also added Time.deltaTime"